# Injection of Services, Business Logic classes and Logger in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, architecture, n-tier-architecture

My application includes the Presentation Layer Project which is the Web-server's project.

In the Startup class of the PL I add a singleton service of type IServiceFacade. The controllers will be injected with it and use it to speak with the lower Service Layer Project functionality (PL Project holds a reference to the ServiceLayer Project).

The ServiceFacade holds an object of type IBusinessLogicFacade and uses it to speak with the lower Business Layer Project (Service Layer Project holds a reference to the Business Logic Project).

I also use the .net Core built-in logging API to inject ILogger to the controllers, the ServiceFacade and the BusinessLogicFacade, this only requires a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Like I added the ServiceFacade as a service, thus enabling the injection, 
I would like to add the BusinessLogicFacade as a service, But this will require a reference from the PL Project to the Business Logic Project, breaking the layer separation.

I could create the BusinessLogicFacade "manually" in the ServiceFacade, but I will then need to supply an ILogger too, because I cannot use the injection of it when creating the BusinessLogicFacade manually.

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceFacade,ServiceFacade> (OK, PL holds a reference to ServiceLayer Project)
services.AddSingleton<IBusinessLogicFacade,BusinessLogicFacade> (Not OK, Requires a reference from PL to BL).
```

Is there a way to receive the some parameters (as the ILogger) through injection when "manually" creating an object?
How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this (dependency reference) is not straightforward to avoid - especially when using the default ASP.Net core container. You could work around this issue using 3rd party DI containers. You can read about [architecture ideas here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures). Specifically for your question, read the "Note" section in the "UI layer types" paragraph (after Figure 5.12 in the [specified link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures)).